# Android saving data in Internal Storage NullPointerException

Tags: android, storage, internal

I have a little problem with writing a file in internal storage from my application.I'm gettin a null pointer exception,but can't find the way to fix it..and actually can't understand which one of the elements is null.

Here is the code that I'm using :

```
hash= jsonObj.getString("hash");
Log.w("CLIENT AUTH HASH","SHOW CLIENT AUTH HASH : "+hash);                  
FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput("autohash",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
out.write(hash.getBytes());
out.close();
```

The class where I'm trying to create and write this file is not an `Activity`, it's just some kind of helper class and that's why it's giving me error when I try to set `context=this;`.
And actually the NullPointerException it thrown at this line :  `FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput("autohash",context.MODE_PRIVATE);`, and I can't get it, which cause this exception :

> 1. The Context

or

> 1. autohash - file (exist or don't).

**Second scenario :**

I have the same function of saving the file in internal storage,but I'm calling that method from another activity.Here is the situation:

I have different packets received over the internet and I'm doing something like this :

```
BasePacket packet; //all other packets extends this class.
byte[] buffer=byte[1024];
//packet calculations
switch(packetType){
  case startPacket:
    packet = new startPacket(/*params*/);
    packet.startExecutePacket();
 case endPacket:
    //same procedure
}
```

and in `startExecutePacket()` I'm trying to save the file.

So any kind of help are welcomed!Thanks in advance!

Comment: how you initialize the context? code or snippet helpful

Comment: Context context; I can't use context=this; because it's giving me an error.I've tried with context.getApplicationContext(); didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CallingActivity.java**

```
onCreate()

helperClass mHelper= new helperClass(CallingActivity.this);
```

**helperClass.java**

```
//declare a context
context refContext;

//constructor
public helperClass(context mContext)
{
   refContext=mContext;
}

//and you code

    hash= jsonObj.getString("hash");
    Log.w("CLIENT AUTH HASH","SHOW CLIENT AUTH HASH : "+hash);                  
    FileOutputStream out = refContext.openFileOutput("autohash",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    out.write(hash.getBytes());
    out.close();
```

try with this one

Comment: Actually that solve my problem for only one Activity.I have another activity where I'm just calling the method which create and save the file..it throws me a nullpointerexception again.I will update my question with the second situation.

Comment: you can do it by same way as above