# Android get Shared Preferences issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` in my application to store the last User id who logged in in my application,and I'm trying to do that from non-activity class, which cause me a `NullPointerException` in the second line of code :

```
Context mContext;
SharedPreferences lastUser = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = lastUser.edit();
```

I've tried with every possible variation of mContext :

- `Acticity.this.mContext;`
- `this.mContext.getApplicationContext();`
- `this.mContext;`

but they didn't solve my problem.
Can anybody give me some solution how to get rid of this problem and how to use Context in static way, without getting `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you had not initialize context of non Activity class, to get away through refer this [Android saving data in Internal Storage NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467190/android-saving-data-in-internal-storage-nullpointerexception/7467255#7467255)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the context of the activity which is calling the that method.

Answer (score 2):

You can try passing the activity context through the constructor of the non-activity class and use this context to create the SharedPreferences object.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    SharedPreferences lastUser = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = lastUser.edit();
```